# SQL Function help- Daylight Savings calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, dst

All,
I wrote a function that essentially takes a timestamp and a shopper ID, and based on that shoppers zipcode work out the UTC offset and correct the time.

The problem I am having is: it's sloooow!

Can anyone see an easy way to speed it up ?

```
    CREATE FUNCTION TimeModifier 
    (
        -- Add the parameters for the function here
       @InputDate datetime,@shopperid int
    )
    RETURNS datetime
AS
  BEGIN



--Declare @shopperid int
--set @shopperid=25

    -- Declare the return variable here


    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result datetime
    Declare @zip nvarchar(10)
    Declare @TimeofYear int
    declare @Year int
    declare @Winter int
    declare @Summer int

    select @year=datepart(yyyy,@InputDate)



--If 0 then its outside of the summer hours. 
    SELECT  @timeofyear=count(*)  FROM [d].[dbo].[DST-Dates] where @inputdate>=startdate and @inputdate<=enddate 


    select @zip=zip from d..shopper  where shopperid=@shopperid


    --Gets the UTC offset for winter and summer
  select @winter=winter,@summer=summer FROM [MMD_Feed].[dbo].[ZipCodeZones] where zip=@zip

  if(@TimeofYear=0)--IE is it Winter
  set @Result=DATEADD(HH,@winter, @Inputdate)
  else--Use summer offset 
  set @Result=DATEADD(HH,@summer, @Inputdate)
  --select @Result

        -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result

END
GO
```

Thanks
~J

Comment: what indexes do you currently have in place?

Comment: There is an index on the zip code tables as well as the DST-Dates table

Comment: am I really going to have to ask you to tell me what their structure is?

Comment: This thing is a scalar function. They are notoriously poor performers. This looks like it could pretty easily be converted to an inline table valued function which would help performance quite a bit. Be vary careful though...if your function has more than 1 statement your performance may actually be worse. Give me a little bit and I think I can get this pretty close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a total shot in the dark for converting this to an iTVF.

```
CREATE FUNCTION TimeModifier 
    (
        -- Add the parameters for the function here
       @InputDate datetime
       , @shopperid int
    )
    RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS RETURN

    select DATEADD(Hour, case when t.TimeOfYear = 0 then z.winter else z.summer end, @InputDate) as MyResult
    from d.dbo.shopper s
    join [MMD_Feed].[dbo].[ZipCodeZones] z on s.zip = z.zip
    cross apply 
    (
        SELECT count(*) as TimeOfYear
        FROM [d].[dbo].[DST-Dates] 
        where @inputdate >= startdate 
            and @inputdate <= enddate 
    ) t
    where s.shopperid = @shopperid
```